# My buttons aren't keeping inside my canvas in html, it's above the canvas but still in the container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using javascript, CSS, and HTML. Not much action in js. The problem is that the buttons do not appear in the canvas-- instead, it is in the container. It is just above my canvas. Also, I am an amateur so I'm sure there are plenty of mistakes I do not realize exist, so any criticism of flaws in the code would be greatly appreciated. I do not think js is affecting the code but even if it was, I'm too piss-poor at it to notice. This is the code:

html:

```
<body>
    
    <div class="container">
        <canvas class="game-canvas"></canvas>
            <div id="text">Text</div>
            <div id="option-buttons" class="btn-grid">
                <button class="btn">Option 1</button>
                <button class="btn">Option 2</button>
                <button class="btn">Option 3</button>
                <button class="btn">Option 4</button>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

css:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  max-width: 80%;
  max-height: 80%;
  outline: 1px solid #333;
  background-color: white;

  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px;
  font-size: 20px;

  transform: scale (3) translateY(50%);
}
.game-canvas {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  height: 170px;
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 4px black solid;
}
.btn-grid {
  padding: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(200px, 1fr)); 
  gap: 60px;
  margin-top: 20px;


}

.btn {
  background-color: hsl(200, 100%, 50%);
  border: 1px solid hsl(200, 100%, 30%);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  height: 200%;
}

.btn:hover {
  border-color: black;
}
```

I tried messing with the css code, though for me it didn't do much to change the general location of the buttons.
In html though, when I tried switching around the code sometimes the buttons just disappear. Other times, it goes out of the container completely.
I'm too scared to touch the javascript code but I don't think it affected the location of the buttons because it was just popups and i can still click the buttons just fine. I don't think it's because the canvas is off? because i put the buttons below a closed canvas. I also tried googling for help and searched for similar questions on this site but I couldn't find any that could help me.

Comment: Try add `position:absolute` in `.btn-grid`, then use left and top control it's offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `position: absoulute` to `position: inherit` at `.game-canvas` element and add `position: absolute` in `.btn-grid` element to solve this problem.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  max-width: 80%;
  max-height: 80%;
  outline: 1px solid #333;
  background-color: white;

  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px;
  font-size: 20px;

  transform: scale (3) translateY(50%);
}
.game-canvas {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  height: 170px;
  position: inherit;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 4px black solid;
}
.btn-grid {
  padding: 10px;
  display: grid;
  position: absolute;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(200px, 1fr)); 
  gap: 60px;
  margin-top: 20px;


}

.btn {
  background-color: hsl(200, 100%, 50%);
  border: 1px solid hsl(200, 100%, 30%);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  height: 200%;
}

.btn:hover {
  border-color: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <canvas class="game-canvas"></canvas>
        <div id="text">Text</div>
        <div id="option-buttons" class="btn-grid">
            <button class="btn">Option 1</button>
            <button class="btn">Option 2</button>
            <button class="btn">Option 3</button>
            <button class="btn">Option 4</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```